# Add email template option to dropdown menu in configuration magento

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

. I try :

```
    <template>
        <email>
            <simpleaffiliate_general_emailtemplate translate="label" module="simpleaffiliate">
                <label>Test Send Email</label>
                <file>test_sendemail.html</file>
                <type>html</type>   
            </simpleaffiliate_general_emailtemplate>

            <simpleaffiliate_general_emailtemplate translate="label" module="simpleaffiliate">
                <label>Test Send Email2</label>
                <file>test_sendemail2.html</file>
                <type>html</type>   
            </simpleaffiliate_general_emailtemplate>
        </email>
    </template>
```

and in system.xml

```
                    <emailtemplate translate="label">
                        <label>Email Template sent to new registered </label>
                        <frontend_type>select</frontend_type>
                        <sort_order>6</sort_order>
                        <source_model>adminhtml/system_config_source_email_template</source_model>
                        <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                        <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                        <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                        <comment></comment>
                    </emailtemplate>
```

but I get only a option  :  Test Sent Email 2 (Default from Locale) , I want add other options . Can you help me :D

Answer (score 0):

You can't have 2 email templates with the same XML node name.  "simpleaffiliate_general_emailtemplate" is used for both.  When it loads in the config the second entry is overwriting the first.